# The name 'View' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When compiling, I get this error: `The name 'View' does not exist in the current context` in reference to my code `return View();`.

Full example code:

```
namespace Controllers
{
public class FilePageController
{
    //
    // GET: /FilePage/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
}
```

I have done this a couple times and been unable to find an answer on SO, so I wanted to post this along with the answer, in case it helps others who have done the same thing as me while learning MVC.

Comment: I would like explanation on why others have marked down this question...

Comment: you have posted question and answer at exactly same time. `22:18:01Z` just over time and you will get it. It gives me an impression that you already knew the answer.

Comment: I did already know the answer.  Posting information you already know the answer to is promoted by SO; see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) and please remove your downvote as it is inconsistent with SO guidelines.

Comment: Great question, this just solved the issue I was having. Sorry that others down voted you :-(

Comment: I just wanted to add a hearty thanks for putting up this answer. You just saved me potentially hours of frustration trying to figure this out. Screw the haters who don't understand SO etiquette, and have an upvote!

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The controller is not inheriting from the `controller` class.  MVC does many things by convention, but naming your class with "Controller" on the end is not enough.

Change it to `public class FilePageController : Controller`.

By the way, `Controller` class inherits from `ControllerBase` class. Hence, members of `ControllerBase` class are accessible from class inherited from `Controller` class.

Answer (score 2):

1. Web Api doesnt contain View so when you create new class inside
   action method return View() use inherited Controller not
   ControllerBase

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller*